# Retriving date from mongo db using node js with incorrect date

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am storing the document like below in mongo db.

```
{
    "username" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "TokenExpires" : ISODate("2015-02-06T05:48:11.837Z"),
    "token" : "2c035545a5059c41a27e1312",
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d0611b6136819118fee461")
}
```

When i retrive the document in node js using mongo db library, i am getting the date for the TokenExpires filed as below

```
    { username: 'abc@gmail.com',
      TokenExpires: Tue Feb 03 2015 11:34:18 GMT+0530 (IST),
      token: '2c035545a5059c41a27e1312',
      _id: 54d0611b6136819118fee461
    }
```

The original date is feb 6, 2015 but it retrieving it as feb 3, 2015.
**Node js script to insert the document:**

```
var doc = {
                username: abc@gmail.com,
                token: 2c035545a5059c41a27e1312,
                TokenExpires:new Date(Date.now()+(3*24*60*60*1000)),
              };
  function create (doc){

        var deferred = Q.defer();
        db.collection("xyz",{safe:true},deferred.makeNodeResolver());
        return deferred.promise.then(function(collection) {
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            collection.save(doc,{safe:true},deferred.makeNodeResolver());
            return deferred.promise.fail(function(err){
                if (err.code === 11000) {
                    err = new Error("document already exists");
                    err.status = 409;
                    return Q.reject(err);
                }
                return Q.reject(err);
            });
        });
    }
```

**Node js script to read:**

```
var doc={
        token:'2c035545a5059c41a27e1312'
    };
 function read (doc) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        db.collection("xyz",{safe:true},deferred.makeNodeResolver());
        return deferred.promise.then(function(collection) {
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            collection.findOne(selector,deferred.makeNodeResolver());
            return deferred.promise
                .fail(function(err){
                    log.error("error finding object",{
                        error:err.toString(),
                        collection: "xyz",
                        selector:selector
                    });
                    return Q.reject(err);
                });
        },function(err){
            log.error("error getting " + "xyz"+ " collection",{error:err.toString()});
            return Q.reject(err);
        });
    }
```

I am using mongodb library 1.3.23.Please anyone help to solve this issue?

Comment: how do you insert the date, as in db.collection.insert({tokeexpires: new Date()});  ??

Comment: Like the below from the node js.To make the expire date valid for 72 hours                                                                                                                    var doc = {
                username: abc@gmail.com,
                token: "2c035545a5059c41a27e1312",
                TokenExpires: new Date(Date.now()+(3*24*60*60*1000)),
            };

Comment: I tried your code, cannot reproduce, the returned valued is the expected one, (Driver 1.3.23 and 1.4.x)- Can you share the full "script" you are using (shell to insert, node to query ?)